# How to resize an SVG animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I am stuck at resizing an svg animation to a different percentages of the page.

I have created a circle that increases its size and then goes back to normal with this:

```
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<circle id="myCircle" cx="600" cy="250" r="70" fill="yellow" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
<animate attributeName="r" values="70; 140; 210; 140; 70" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</circle>
</svg>
```

Then, when I change the área size of the svg, the circle does not change its size nor the position within this area.

I have tried to scale the animation with CSS giving size to the body in pixels and then assign an area to the SVG in percentages:

```
body{
width: 1440px;
heigth: 990px
}

#mySVG{
width: 100%;
}
```

Also, I tried to change size with javascript:

```
function resize(){
var svg = document.getElementById("mySVG");
        svg.style.width = window.innerWidht;
svg.style.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

None of them worked…  wondering what is the best method to scale SVG animations not only with this circle but with SVG animations in general.

Thank’s in advanced.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a viewbox to define the co-ordinate space. E.G.

```
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
 viewbox="0 0 1200 1200">
```

> The viewBox attribute allows to specify that a given set of graphics
>   stretch to fit a particular container element.
>
> The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers min-x,
>   min-y, width and height, separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which
>   specify a rectangle in user space which should be mapped to the bounds
>   of the viewport established by the given element, taking into account
>   attribute preserveAspectRatio.

```html
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 1200 1200">
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="600" cy="250" r="70" fill="yellow" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="70; 140; 210; 140; 70" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Useful [**SVG Resource Article**](http://css-tricks.com/mega-list-svg-information/) @ CSS-Tricks.com

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)